# Passing Datas from cshtml to custom edit for not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my code in `.cshtml`. I want to pass value of css to my custom edit for but not working.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.xxx, new { size = 20, maxLength = 10 , css = "test"  })
```

my code in custom edit for.

```
@model string

@{
    int size = 50;
    int maxLength = 50;
    string type = "text";
    string css = "";

    if (ViewData["size"] != null)
    {
        size = (int)ViewData["size"];
    }
    if (ViewData["maxLength"] != null)
    {
        maxLength = (int)ViewData["maxLength"];
    }
    if (ViewData["type"] != null)
    {
        type = (string)ViewData["type"];
    }
    if (ViewData["css"] != null)
    {
        css = (string)ViewData["css"];
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { Size = size, MaxLength = maxLength, Type = type, @class = css})
```

Comment: what version of MVC do you use? And your `model.xxx` is `string` type?

Comment: yes it's a string type. gonna change the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i reproduce your example on MVC 4 and i suppose you should just escape `css` property name in `EditorFor` hepler for then it works. Here you are:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.xxx, new { size = 20, maxLength = 10 , @css = "test"  })
```

Comment: is it a reserved word?

Comment: @DerpukuDer i think - yes