# ASP.NET MVC htmlAttributes escaping words list in HtmlHelpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In MVC almost every html helper has overload that takes `IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes` parameter. There you can pass anonymouse object and properties will be `input` attributes after **Razor** render page.

But there is some property names that should be escaped with `@` char. For example `@class`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyProperty, new { @class = "my-class" })
```

Is there a list of this kind of words that should be escaped?

Are they change with changes of **MVC** 3,4,5 and versions of **Razor**?

Are they different for different Html Helpers?

Plus i whould like to know why should we escape exatly this words if someone could explain.

Comment: The only names that need to be escaped are those that are [reserved keywords in c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx). There are no difference between different versions of MVC (its a c# issue)

Comment: @StephenMuecke but check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33411073/1849444). `css` not on the list, but....

Comment: That question makes no sense - `css="someValue"` is not a valid html attribute. The only 2 names that make sense to escape are `@class` - to output `class="someClassName"` -  and `@readonly` (to output `readonly="readonly"`

Comment: In any case I just tested `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyProperty, new { css = "test" })` and it outputs `<input css="test" ... />` - there is no need to escape it (its invalid html, but it works)

Comment: @StephenMuecke but if you see in that question it's `@Html.EditorFor` helper and MVC 5. That's why i asking this question.

Comment: Should not make any difference (but can't test at the moment because only have MVC-4 on this machine)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's what i've been thinking about but the case exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to **reserved identifiers**  and **contextual identifiers**.

1. Reserved identifiers are always reserved keywords in C#.
2. Contextual keywords are sometimes reserved keywords in C#.

Reserved identifiers cannot be used within the language except as that predefined identifier that we all understand it to be. Contextual identifiers can be used within your program when not used within the context for which they are reserved.

As with any word that is or is being used as an keyword within the context of your program you need to use the escape key `@` in your razor.

> Keywords are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your program unless they include @ as a prefix. For example, @if is a valid identifier but if is not because if is a keyword.

I have provided you with two alphabetised lists of reserved and contextual modifiers.

[C# Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx)

**Reserved Identifiers**

- abstract
- as
- base
- bool
- break
- byte
- case
- catch
- char
- checked
- class
- const
- continue
- decimal
- default
- delegate
- do
- double
- else
- enum
- event
- explicit
- extern
- false
- finally
- fixed
- float
- for
- foreach
- goto
- if
- implicit
- in
- in (generic-modifier)
- int
- interface
- internal
- is
- lock
- long
- namespace
- new
- null
- object
- operator
- out
- out (generic-modifier)
- override
- params
- private
- protected
- public
- readonly
- ref
- return
- sbyte
- sealed
- short
- sizeof
- stackalloc
- static
- string
- struct
- switch
- this
- throw
- true
- try
- typeof
- uint
- ulong
- unchecked
- unsafe
- ushort
- using
- virtual
- void
- volatile
- while

> Contextual keywords have special meaning only in a limited program context and can be used as identifiers outside that context. Generally, as new keywords are added to the C# language, they are added as contextual keywords in order to avoid breaking programs written in earlier versions.

**Contextual keywords**

- add
- alias
- ascending
- async
- await
- descending
- dynamic
- from
- get
- global
- group
- into
- join
- let
- orderby
- partial (type)
- partial (method)
- remove
- select
- set
- value
- var
- where (generic type constraint)
- where (query clause)
- yield

*Also wish to acknowledge  [Stephen Meucke's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) contributions in the comments.*

Comment: I agree Reserved Identifiers can not be used there. But about your Contextual keywords i try this:  `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { add = "test", alias = "test2"})` and the result was like this `<input add="test" alias="test2"  id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">`. So i don't understand in the end what actuall list of escaped properties.